# Cairngorm Code Generator

Tags: eclipse, plugins, generator, cairngorm

I was wondering if there's a code generator for Cairngorm that can be installed as a plugin in Eclipse? No code generator like in WebORB, FluorineFX that inspects the DataBase and generates a whole lot of code. I just want a plugin for eclipse where I can give in some options and properties. Then the plugin generates the appropriate event, command and delegate. If the Delegate for instance would allready exist, the new remote call would have to be appended to the Delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic eclipse plugin on the adobe open source site

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Plugin